# Keep getting Entitytype has no key defined

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I know this question is a duplicate, but unfortunately I did not find the solution to my problem. Even though there are a lot of posts on this matter.

So, like the topic says, I am getting the exception saying:

```
entitytype has no key defined
```

My model looks like this:

```
public class QuestionModel
{               
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Question")]
    public string Question { get; set; }

    public List<string> Responses { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Number of answers")]
    public int NumberOfAnswers { get; set; }
}
```

And the code in controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult RegisterQuestion(QuestionModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            using (var context = new DataBaseContext())
            {
                var question = new QuestionModel
                {
                    NumberOfAnswers = model.NumberOfAnswers,
                    Question = model.Question,
                    Responses = model.Responses
                };

                context.Question.Add(question);

                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }

        return View("RegisteredQuestion");
    }
```

Reading several posts, this exception might occur if:

1. Key is missing: (I do have a key, here called ... `int ID {...}`
2. Class name is not equal to ID member name: (This is not a problem for me here, using `int ID`)
3. Member does not have getter/setter: (But I do have gettter and setter)
4. The ID member is not public: (All my properties are public)
5. Confusion in Entity Framework when multiple IDs are present. For example:

   public int oneID { get; set; }
   public int anotherID { get; set; }
   But this is not a problem in my case, as I only have one ID. But just in case, I did try adding the Key annotation, so my id property became:
   `[Key]
   public int ID { get; set; }`

But no luck. I have taken note about any reaons for this error that I came across, but I still miss out someting. Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: Have you tried marking the ID with the [Key] attribute?

Comment: For completeness, also post the full exception details and your DbContext. Also, what version of EF?

Comment: You've got your reponses as a collection of strings instead of a collection of Response. Not sure how EF will deal with that. Do you have a response class (ie QuestionModelId, etc)?

Answer (score 0):

I restarted my VS13 (which I don't do very often, since it's always open). which helped. Normally I just rebuild the project, which is enough. But there must have been something funny going on.
Sorry for wasting your time. I wasted my own time too for not restarting VS, but I never thought of this option.